# Is there any way to copy the value of all the parameters of a method in debug mode in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Yesterday, my boss did it again... He opened the code, changed the type of one of the parameters, saved the file, compiled (no errors) and committed the changes. After that, asked me to try his changes and tell him if I find any errors. Of course I found them and now I have to tell him exactly what to change and with what values to call the method so he can change it comfortably. The problem is that the function has many parameters. Is there any way to copy all those values automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is, but I expect an issue with this might be that, since method parameters can be complex objects, it could be difficult to store such parameters in a meaningful form. An obvious choice, of course, would be JSON.

Comment: You should convince your boss to stop "coding". ;) Obviously he is an impediment for your team.

Comment: As an aside, functions with many parameters are usually an indication of other problems, perhaps pointing to a need to refactor here - introduce a settings object instead of multiple parameters, or use subclassing for when the method can do many different things, as two examples.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly, but it's code I didn't write, and quite old. I can´t convince my boss to change it.

Comment: @amedina But _he_ changed it ... so, he is allowed to change it and have you deal with the consequences but you cannot refactor for higher quality? Smells like toxic environment.

Comment: @Fildor It's a toxic environment.